# Regex to validate string having only lower case, first char must be a letter

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I want to use the Regex to validate the string containing

- must contain only lower case letters
- first char must be a letter.
- remaining characters must match regex `[a-z0-9_.]`

I use the `/^[\w\s\-.]*$/` to validate the string. But it allows the first character like (._)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just stick to your requirements ?

- first char must be a lowercase letter: `[a-z]`
- remaining characters must match: `[a-z0-9_.]`

-> your regex: `/^[a-z][a-z0-9_.]*$/`

Answer (score 2):

When you put a period inside square brackets, it is interpreted as a literal period. That's one reason why your regex doesn't work. What you want is this:

```
input =~ /^[a-z][a-z0-9_.]*$/
```

Note that the first character is handled with one character class and the remaining characters by another, which is what the specification calls for. You can't pull it off with a single character class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 data = "helloworld_12_."
 data =~/^[a-z][a-z\d._]*$/
 puts $&
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work for you.

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d._]*/

/                  - Start of Regex
^                  - The string will start with a lowercase letter
[a-z\d._]*         - The string will have zero or more lowercase letters, digits, etc.
/                  - End of Regex
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You need both anchors; `"ab12._c%%%"[/^[a-z][a-z\d._]*/]
=> "ab12._c"`.